# Catch block string/number validation

Tags: java

In catch block i want to print enter valid card no if someone enters a 
string or a number less than 13 or greater than 16.

I have just added numberformatexception but it does nothing in case i input a string or a number a number less than 13 or greater than 16.

How to have the exception here? This code is for validating credit card.I just need help in try catch block

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

//CreditCard class
public class CreditCard {
    //Variable declaration

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JLabel label;
    private JLabel resLabel;
    private JButton validateBtn;

    //Constructor
    public CreditCard() {

        frame = new JFrame("Credit Card Details");
        frame.setSize(350, 350);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // create a new panel and add the frame to the panel.
        panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        // add label
        label = new JLabel("Enter Credit Card No.");
        label.setBounds(10, 20, 165, 25);
        panel.add(label);

        // add input text
        textField = new JTextField(16);
        textField.setBounds(10, 50, 165, 25);
        panel.add(textField);

        // create a validation button
        validateBtn = new JButton("Validate");
        validateBtn.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
        panel.add(validateBtn);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        // set label as valid or invalid
        resLabel = new JLabel();
        resLabel.setBounds(180, 50, 265, 25);
        panel.add(resLabel);

        // add event listener
        validateBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                String text = textField.getText();
                if (text.length() < 13 || text.length() > 16) {
                    resLabel.setText("Entered Value Must Be Between 13-16 Chars");
                    return;
                }
                boolean isValid = validateText(text);
                if(isValid)
                    resLabel.setText("Credit Card is Valid");
                else
                    resLabel.setText("Credit Card is Invalid");
                }catch(NumberFormatException f){
                    System.out.println("Enter Valid Card Number");
                }

            }

            private boolean validateText(String text) {
                int rSum = 0, lSum = 0;
                for (int i = text.length() - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
                    if (!Character.isDigit(text.charAt(i)))
                        return false;
                    int currentNum = Character.getNumericValue(text.charAt(i));
                    currentNum *= 2;
                    if (currentNum > 9) {
                        int tempSum = 0;
                        while (currentNum >= 10) {
                            tempSum += currentNum % 10;
                            currentNum /= 10;
                        }
                        tempSum += currentNum;
                        currentNum = tempSum;
                    }
                    rSum += currentNum;
                }
                System.out.println(rSum);
                for (int i = text.length() - 1; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
                    if (!Character.isDigit(text.charAt(i)))
                        return false;
                    int currentNum = Character.getNumericValue(text.charAt(i));
                    lSum += currentNum;
                }
                System.out.println(lSum);
                int totalSum = lSum + rSum;
                if (totalSum % 10 == 0)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use catch just to validate input, what you need to do you can do with simple loop, something like while(input.length < 13 || input.length > 16) System.out.println("Please enter valid card number, 13 to 16 digits: "); *read new CC number and store it in appropriate variable here* }

Comment: NumberFormatException is never `thrown` for it to be caught

Comment: You've already got all the `if` and `else` statements you need, to do the validation.  I'm not sure why you want to add exceptions to it.

Comment: Yes but the requirement is to validate using try/catch and in case of a string or number <13 and <16 it should throw an exception that "Enter a valid credit card no"

Answer (score 0):

If you want an exception to be thrown, you have to include it in the code. You can achieve it by adding "`throw new NumberFormatException()`" in the place you want it to happen.

Anyway it is not the best idea to throw an exception in the situation you described, because throwing an exception stops your program from running the "normal" way. I would suggest using an "`if`" statement to check an input - if the input satisfies you, you go on, but if not - you provide next inputs (with an infinite while loop surrounding mentioned "`if`" statement, that ends its work when the correct input is done) or simply with writing an error message.